# Need to stop execution Javascript onlick function by element onclick function

Tags: javascript

```
<input type = "button" onclick="test()">
```

Js sample code:

```
$('input[type=button]').on('click',(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
      if(!window.confirm(message)) {
         return false;
       }
   }));
```

I need to stop execution `test()` for other purposes when click on button. But current situation is it also calling `test()` instead of return `false`. Can anyone give suggestion?

Comment: Remove the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi but the markup is automatically generated so I can not remove it.

Comment: @imran - if you can target the element, you _can_ remove the handler. It's just a matter of `element.removeAttribute('onclick');` where element is a reference to the button. ;)

Comment: @ enhzflep - but next time  again need the onclick function if he confirms :P

Comment: @imran - If I'd neglected to add detail to the question which would affect the answer given, I certainly wouldn't be sticking out my tongue in the comment that I admitted my mistake. ;)

Comment: How about overriding the `test()` function with an additional confirmation check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the onclick event from the HTML markup and add it manually to your code if the user does confirm. It requires you to know which function is associated to the onclick markup attribute and may be complicated if it changes depending on the circumstances. Would this work for you?

```
// we remove the onclick attribute from the HTML
$('input[type=button]').removeAttribute('onclick');

$('input[type=button]').on('click',(function(e){
   if(!window.confirm(message)) {
       // if user does not confirm, do nothing
       return false;
   } else {
       // if user does confirm, then proceed with the test() function
       test();
   }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to first unbind the previously active onclick:

```
$('input[type=button]').unbind( 'click' );
$('input[type=button]').on('click',(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
      if(!window.confirm(message)) {
         return false;
       }
   }));
```